# Persisting session on page refresh

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We have Amplify handling our communication with Cognito and this works as it's supposed to. Amplify is configured to use S3 bucket as its storage.

A new request has emerged to use a token to perform signing in. I have implemented it so, that UI calls API with that token and API performs adminInitiateAuth and receives new id and access tokens. UI receives them, stores them in local storage and uses them in API requests and that also works just fine.

The problem arises when user does a page refresh. Amplify determines that use is not logged in (*amplifyService.authStateChange$* submits signed_out state) and there's a snippet in our code that subscribes to those events and does the log out functionality when the state is signed_out.

Does it make sense storing tokens in local storage? If not, where should I keep them?

How does Amplify determine if user is logged in or not (*Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()* maybe)?

When do these authStateChange events fire?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Auth.`currentAuthenticatedUser()` will persist authentication for you, you just need to call it whenever a page refreshed or mounted here is a React.js example that persist auth whenever App renders :

```
App.js


useEffect(()=>{
   const checkAuthenticatedUser = async () => {
   const user = await currentAuthenticatedUser()
   setUser(user) 
 }
},[])
```